# Strange strings in executable VC++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I created simple C++ Hello world program, then I compiled it using MSVC++, and then I looked into executable using Notepad++ (I know it is not the best program to open binary files with it, but I wanted to know, if there are any human readable strings). I found there strings like `A cast to a smaller data type has caused a loss of data.  If this was intentional, you should mask the source of the cast with the appropriate bitmask.`

```
The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

What are those strings, and where they came from, and how I can get rid of them?

Comment: Are you building in DEBUG mode or in RELEASE mode ? Me think DEBUG will keep a lot of data (string or other) in the executable.

Comment: The standard library includes messages in case of a fair number of common errors.

Answer (score 1):

All constant strings are human readable through the use of a text editor. Try looking for "hello world" in your program and it will pop up. (ran into this for the first time when we were trying to figure out if obfuscating our opencl code was worth it...it wasn't).

These strings are the error strings that windows throws on top of every executable. I have no idea how to get rid of them.

Comment: Maybe because they cause larger executable size?

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović I should clarify that is may be worth it in other cases, it just wasn't worth it in ours.

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović Of course they do! Building in debug mode causes usage of additional RAM/ROM. Build in release mode to get rid of them.

Comment: @g-makulik It should be noted that const strings are human readable in a text editor REGARDLESS of whether or not it is release or debug mode. Essentially, they are stored in the file as `char`s, and thus can be read as `char`s in a text editor.